# How to refresh specific DataGrid Column-Cell Value without refreshing the entire table

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So I have the following code meant to audit our inventory. Upon editing the `actual_quantity` cell on the DataGrid, the `ItemAuditInstance` instance automatically gets updated, setting its `actual_quantity` as well as calculating for its`difference`. My problem is the DataGrid automatically refreshes the cell for `actual_quantity` but not `difference`

I know you can force a refresh by setting the DataGrid's ItemsSource to null then back to the list but it seems like a waste of resources as I don't want to refresh hundreds of rows for only one value. Is there any way to do it this?

ItemAuditInstance:

```
public class ItemAuditInstance : ReflectionObject {

    public int id { get; set; }
    public int bfk_item_audit_id { get; set; }
    public string item { get; set; }
    public int current_quantity { get; set; }
    public int actual_quantity { get; set; }
    public int difference { get; set; }

    public int ds_actual_quantity { 
        get {
            return actual_quantity;
        }
        set {
            actual_quantity = value;
            difference = current_quantity - actual_quantity;
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgItems" Margin="0,0,0,50" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" RowEditEnding="dgItems_RowEditEnding">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding item}" Header="Item" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding current_quantity}" Header="Current Quantity" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ds_actual_quantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Actual Quantity" IsReadOnly="False"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding difference}" Header="Difference" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the ItemAuditInstance class and set UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged in the cell binding (just like you have in the binding of ds_actual_quantity) for such behavior.
In your example the binding of actual quantity is set right, however without INotifyPropertyChanged it may sometimes not work right.
I suggest using backing private fields to allow silent changes (sometimes needed to avoid infinite loops)

Your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged should look like:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
}
private int _difference;
public int Difference
{
    get
    {
        return _difference;
    }
    set
    {
        _difference = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Difference"));
    }
}
```

along with XAML:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Difference, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Difference" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*"/>
```

Now just set
    Difference = current_quantity - actual_quantity 
and the binding should be automatically updated

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! My apologies though, I don't think I explained my problem well. It isn't that `difference` isn't getting updated - it is. It's that the cell on the DataGrid representing `difference` isn't refreshing. I.e. when difference becomes 25, the cell still shows 0.

Comment: The "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" is responsible for telling the cell to monitor updates. By default, UpdateSourceTrigger is set to "OneTime", which only reads the value in one case- when the ItemsSource is changed (the whole collection)
With PropertyChanged, the binding is waiting for signal that the property has changed- it is given by the INotifyPropertyChanged interface as shown in my answer (by OnProperyChanged method)- I have shown you the way to notify your datagrid that a change has happened and it should update its values. Hope it's easier to understand now

Comment: Wait, I'm dumb, sorry. I didn't realize I had to inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `ItemAuditInstance`. Once I did that, your code worked. Thank you so much!